# Responsive textboxes and a null 'Select' option in loaded list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select boxes, one is for products and the other is for product type. what a appears in the product type list is dependent on what is selected in the product.  What i want to achieve is a null option at the top of the loaded list so that i can search just on the product. How would i go about this?

so far i have

```
<select class="form-control" name="product_type" id="producttype">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

and JS/jquery

```
$('#product').on('change', function(e) {
  console.log(e);

  var prod_id = e.target.value;

  $.get('/ajax-subcat?prod_id=' + prod_id, function(data) {
    $('#producttype').empty();

    $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj) {
      $('#producttype').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.id + '">' + subcatObj.name + '</option>');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: A default Option <option value="">Select a product type"</option> at the top of my loaded list. so i can search on a null value for that select box

Comment: You can add a first option with <option selected="selected"> so that will be the default one, right?

Comment: Nope gets knocked out by the loaded list. it needs to be something in the JS.

Comment: I mean in the JS. you are appending options there, so outside your $.each you can do something like: $('#producttype').append('<option selected disabled>Select a product type</option>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append that default options before filling your select in the each, something like this:

```
$('#product').on('change', function(e) {
  console.log(e);

  var prod_id = e.target.value;

  $.get('/ajax-subcat?prod_id=' + prod_id, function(data) {
    $('#producttype').empty();

    $('#producttype').append('<option selected disabled>Select a product type</option>');

    $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj) {
      $('#producttype').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.id + '">' + subcatObj.name + '</option>');
    });
  });
});
```